# Android : Navigation Drawer List overlapping Action Bar using SystemBarTint Lib

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I'm using [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library in my application and my navigation drawer list is overlapping action bar.

Screenshot can be found here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZFVz.jpg

Please someone help me out!

Here is my layout of navigation drawer >>

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:clipToPadding="false"
 >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_content_padding"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_size"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
    android:background="#111"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try no use this library "SystemBarTint"?

Comment: Advantage of SystemBarTint is that it helps my app support tinted status bar on earlier versions of Android. Can you help me doing it without the dependency of SystemBarTint ?

Comment: Only try no use "SystemBarTint" To see if it works. If it works without the library already do another question.

Comment: @TeRRo, idk how to do it without the use of SystemBarTint library, I'm new to Android. Can you provide me necessary docs and resources ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, fixed it by wrapping my drawer activity with a "FrameLayout"
These two lines must be added to the framelayout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

So your layout will be like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clipToPadding="false">
..
..
..
<!--Your layout-->
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code in your project:

```
SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
// enable status bar tint
tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
// enable navigation bar tint
tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Then how should I implement Tinted status bar in my application without that library ?